# insufficient funds for gas

Tags: sendtransaction

sorry I'm too stupid to transfer eth from one account to another.

I want to transfer all eth from one wallet to the other.
With eth.getbalance the value is: 26303362261697318
About 0.12193 eth

web3.eth.sendTransaction({
from: "0xssss",
to: "0xtttt",
gas: "0x76c0",
gasPrice: "0x9184e72a000",
value: "0x52CA48D5AE4326"
})

but I always get back errors like "insufficient funds for gas"

Can please someone give me the exact numbers for gas, gasprice and my eth value to transfer the all from one wallet to the other?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction), you can't pass a hexadecimal to the *value* argument:

> value - Number|String|BN|BigNumber: (optional) The value transferred
> for the transaction in wei, also the endowment if it’s a
> contract-creation transaction.

Example:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    value: '1000000000000000'
}).then(console.log);
```

Additionally, you should also explicitly set a *gas* limit using gas:

> gas - Number: (optional, default: To-Be-Determined) The amount of gas
> to use for the transaction (unused gas is refunded).